# How to cluster nodes together in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

My graph is 1M nodes. The data model is intentionally simple. There are Entities and IDType nodes. A single Entity may have 1:many IDType nodes. And an IDType node may be connected to 1:many Entities. This forms the graph.

The goal is to find all clusters of IDType's and Entities that are connected together into what I call a cluster of nodes (subgraph I guess some call it). Imagine if we had 1M nodes. I would like to find "clusters" like this in the graph data, I'm trying to figure out how to do that. I've written the cypher query that I believe does it, but it's not clear to me if it's doing what is intended.

The question: how do I efficiently traverse my graph and cluster together nodes so that there is a single row or group of rows that I can return as a row-based result set to my python driver program to then operate over that cluster. While this doesn't need to be the exact structure of my result, this is a sense of what I'm looking for.

cluster|nodes
1|2,3,4,5,6,7
2|10,11,12,13
3|15,17,19,20,21,25,27,28,33

Where the "cluster" is some arbitrary clustering of the list of nodes (frankly if I have a single line that's just a collection of clusters or some other way of telling they are all related, then I'm golden). The "nodes" number represents a unique integer-based property that we tag to every Entity node.

The query is below. The concept is that an "Entity" node can have 1 or many "ID" nodes and I'm trying to get all "Entity" and "ID" that are related to each other through the relationship "HAS_ID".

Conceptually, if there is a relationship that exists in the data like this Entity1-->ID1<--Entity2-->ID2<--Entity3-->ID3<--Entity4-->ID4<--Entity5 then I want to "cluster" them together so that I can create a unique number that represents this group of nodes. With my example, there are 5 entities, but there could just as easily be 2 entities, or 50 entities, which are all related to one another, that's why I'm thinking the variable length path is what I need.

The below is my attempt to do this in the graph. But 1) is it correct? 2) is it efficient because it seems to runs indefinitely 3) how do i best "group" these together?

```
match 
(n:Entity)-[e1:HAS_ID*]-(o)
where n.key <> o.key
return *
limit 10
;
```

I've also tried

```
match (n:Entity)-[e1:HAS_ID*]-(o)
where n.key <> o.key
with distinct n.key as key_1, o.key as key_2
return key_1, collect(key_2)
limit 100
;
```

This *seems* to do close to what I want, but I'm still not getting a single group for a given key, in other words, I can have 5 rows returned but they are all still related, which I'd rather have 1 row in that case... He's an example, you can see that key "49518" is on the first and second row, I'd rather have one row that grouped them all together.

```
49518   [49004, 49871, 49940, 50525, 49101, 49625, 50165, 50017, 49098, 50383]
49940   [49088, 49706, 50292, 50470, 49140, 49258, 49216, 49559, 50004, 50346, 49237, 49518, 49894, 49101, 49625, 50165, 50017, 49098, 50383]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one, your query doesn't match the relationship pattern you described.

Each of your arrows in your pattern is a [:HAS_ID] relationship, so if entities and IDs are always alternating between each relationship, then your current query would only match patterns like this:

```
(:Entity)-[:HAS_ID]->(:ID)<-[:HAS_ID]-(:Entity)-[:HAS_ID]->(:ID)<-[:HAS_ID]-(:Entity)
```

3 entities, 2 IDs, 4 relationships. That doesn't match your example pattern of 5 entities, 4 IDs, and 8 relationships. So at the very least, you'll want to alter your pattern to use *8.

As for efficiency...the thing you're trying to do seems rather inefficient, as it must attempt to find this pattern on every single :Entity node in your graph, trying every single :HAS_ID relationship it finds. If your entire graph is made of this same pattern of :Entity and :ID and :HAS_ID, then your query is going to be traversing your entire graph, not once but multiple times.

You are going to get duplicate results. Even if we assume that your entire graph is made up of isolated 5 entity / 4 ID / 8 relationship chains like a snake, as in your example (an entity either being at the end of the chain with one link to an ID, or somewhere in the middle with links to 2 IDs), then you'll be getting 2 matches for that same group of nodes, one matching from one end of the chain, the other matching the other end. And that's the simple case...I'm guessing your graph could be much more complex than this, allowing even more possibilities for many different patterns to match on the exact same group of nodes. A unique path using your pattern does not equate to a unique grouping of nodes.

At the very least, you'll probably want to match on a pattern and use RETURN DISTINCT NODES(p) to enforce unique sets of nodes, but I still think the matching may take quite a bit of time.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply and detail. I am still stumped ;(. I don't feel I did too well describing the details of my problem so let me see if I can fill in some blanks into my question above.

Comment: I've updated my question, please let me know if this is more helpful.

Comment: Ah, so you're looking for the entire grouping, no matter how small or large, and each grouping should be a complete subgraph, with no [:HAS_ID] connections from the subgraph to any other ID or Entity? Tricky problem...